# Каким образом файлы использовавшиеся для сборки сайта доступны в Sources в DevTools?

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

Не чего не понимаю, эти файлы использовались для сборки, но их нет в итоговом бандле. Бандл загружен на хостинг, и как я могу их вообще видеть в DevTools, если их нет на хостинге?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кеш, как вариант.

Comment: Так вы узнали что у вас включён source map